# Removing a repetitive item in a list, ignores other items

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

i have a list of words in Polish and i want to remove the single words in this list. that means i only want sentences. that's why i have a an ***If*** with this condition `if len(item.split())<=1:` . the Problem occourse when i run the function. it removes only this word: ***`Powrót`*** and ignores the words that come after it like `Energetyka`.

```
_webTextList=['MOTORYZACJA', 'Szukaj w serwisie', 'Powrót', 'Energetyka', 'Powrót', 'Gazownictwo', 'Powrót', 'Górnictwo', 'Powrót', 'Hutnictwo', 'Powrót', 'Nafta', 'Powrót', 'Chemia', ...]#the list of words and sentenses.

def remove_one_words_from_list(_webTextList):
 for item in _webTextList:
   if len(item.split())<=1:
     _webTextList.remove(item)
 return _webTextList
```

i can not figure out what i'm doing wrong. tnx for the help.

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and keep the strings that contain a space:

```
_webTextList = ['MOTORYZACJA', 'Szukaj w serwisie', 'Powrót', 'Energetyka', 'Powrót', 'Gazownictwo', 'Powrót', 'Górnictwo', 'Powrót', 'Hutnictwo', 'Powrót', 'Nafta', 'Powrót', 'Chemia']

_webTextList = [s for s in _webTextList if ' ' in s]
```

*NB. if you really want to use the length of split's output as condition: `[s for s in _webTextList if len(item.split())>1]`.*

Output: `['Szukaj w serwisie']`